# Junit - Running 1 test works, multiple fail on Assertion

Tags: java, junit

I am having an issue where if I try running multiple tests of a similar type as what is shown below, the test fails on the assertTrue call. Running a test case separately or in the debugger gives the expected results though. I tried researching this obviously, and it said that maybe I wasn't cleaning up correctly, so I added the @After annotation. This Dao test is using an in-memory hsql database. I'm still not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
    public class ConfigDaoTest
    {
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigDaoTest.class);
        private static final String DOC_ID="12345678";
        private static final String STATUS_INDICATOR="S";
        private static final String FILE_NAME="Testing.txt";
        private DaoTestResources resources;
    
        @Before
        public void setUp()
        {
            resources = new DaoTestResources();
            System.setProperty("IS_JUNIT_TEST", "TRUE");
        }
        
        @After
        public void cleanUp()
        {
            resources = null;
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testUpdateNotice() {
            boolean retVal = false;
    
            try {
                retVal = new ConfigDao(ConfigurationManager.getInstance("test/resources/junit.test.properties")).updateNoticeByFileName(FILE_NAME,DOC_ID,STATUS_INDICATOR);
    
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.debug("ErrorText:" + e.getMessage());
                assertNotNull(true);
            }
            assertTrue(retVal);
            System.out.println("Return value: " + retVal);
            assertNotNull(retVal);
        }
      
        // More tests like the above.

}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Also, never: have a flag that indicates a JUnit test is running, and never catch exceptions in tests.

Comment: Let's just say I've been tasked with fixing a bunch of test cases which were never designed or implemented properly, and there are limitations right now on what I can do, which is why the test case is in this state. However, I was able to resolve this on my own. I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why this worked for me (if someone does know, I would love to know the technical details), but I removed cleanUp() and changed @Before to @BeforeClass, and now each of my test cases is running as expected when built with ant both from CL and Eclipse. My best guess is that there was some issue being caused by initializing the hsqldb before each test - that's what the resource class does.